# Minidump everytime I upload a delimited text file

Tags: qgis, text, minidump

I am having a problem loading delimited text files into QGIS 2.18.8 Las Palmas (the same error also happened in past versions). Every time I try to upload a delimited text file the following error  happens:

> Minidump in C: qgis-20170524-101344-6300-16268-cde1d78.dmp

I have tried disabling and uninstalling all plugins, and have deleted the .qgis2 folder (older suggestions from other posts). But I am still not having any luck.

I am using Windows 10.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the delimited text file loaded in a text editor and the options you used when trying to import it to QGIS please?

Comment: I have the same problem with windows 8.1.

Comment: However I only had it for a few days. 
It also happens with files that were previously perfectly fine

For me the things that happened recently and could have any influence on it are :
- I updated from 2.18.7 to 2.18.8,  
- My C: drive got completely filled up
- I tried to read a badly formatted file, and messed up with the defaults parameters

Comment: There is a bug: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16600#change-79959

Install a  Version <> 2.18.8.